# vba Row numbers for filtered rows

Tags: vba, excel

I have this code to capture the row number in a filtered table, do some things and then go to the next visible row. I works great for the first row.

```
Sub test()

Dim rn As Long
Dim cell As Range
Dim rng As Range


    Set rng = Sheets("FabricatedParts").Range("A:A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        rn = Sheets("FabricatedParts").UsedRange.Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Row
         For Each cell In rng
            With ActiveSheet
                .Range("B14").Value = [Parts].Cells(rn, [Parts[Part.]].Column)
            End With
            'rn = Next Visible Row #???.row
         Next cell

End Sub
```

When I change to offset(1, 0) to offset(2, 0) it still returns the row number for the first visible row(in this case 10). I am looking for a VBA statement that will return the row number for the next visible row and pass that number to the rn variable. For the filtered range I am testing the next row number is 11, the next 165, the next 166 etc. Thank you for your time.

Comment: You have already set the range (`rng`) to Visible cells only, so when you are looping, you will loop to the next visible cell. You can change `rn` to `cell.row` By your code, it looks like you are changing the same cell many times, one could assume there is only one instance of what you are looking for. Try using `find()` instead of looping through the entire range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the row number of the cell loop.

```
Sub test()

Dim rn As Long
Dim cell As Range
Dim rng As Range


    Set rng = Sheets("FabricatedParts").Range("A:A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
         For Each cell In rng
            rn = cell.row
            With ActiveSheet
                .Range("B14").Value = [Parts].Cells(rn, [Parts[Part.]].Column)
            End With
         Next cell

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I think I have another issue however. The values I am getting in cell "B14" are coming from the next row down instead of the filtered data(12 instead of 11, 162 instead of 161 etc.). I'm sure it's because I haven't defined the rng better. How would I get the filtered data body range for column A?

Comment: You are filtering on `Sheets("FabricatedParts").Range("A:A")`, but pulling data from `[Parts].Cells`. How is `Parts` calculated?

Comment: "Parts" is a table showing all the components and labor to fabricate parts in our business. Column A has the part #. The filter is based on which customer. So the goal is to build a report for all the parts for a certain customer. So this small piece of code is to fill in the part # in cell B14 of the report. Once I get this part to work there are many more values in the Parts table that will be used to build the report. So the "rng" can be any range that shows the filtered results. (excluding headers)

Comment: I changed the range statement to: Set rng = Sheets("FabricatedParts").ListObjects(1).DataBodyRange.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) and it works perfectly. Many thanks for your help.